# Relation with same extension with different properties

Tags: set-theory, relations

Suppose there are two relations where  $R' \subseteq A' \times A'$ and $R \subseteq A \times A$ where $A \subset A'$ and $R =  R'$ . For $R$ the condition of reflexivity holds, since $\forall x \in A; xRx$, but $\exists x \in A'; \neg(xR'x)$, so reflexivity does not hold for R'.

Given a principle for equality, $R = R' \Rightarrow \forall \mathfrak{F} (\mathfrak{F}R' \Leftrightarrow \mathfrak{F}R)$. This should hold for the specific instance of reflexivity of a relation.

Are there different properties for extensionally identical objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different ways we can think about a relation: as simply a set of ordered pairs, or as a set of ordered pairs *together with* an explicit domain and codomain. Some properties - like symmetry and transitivity - make sense for the first approach, while others explicitly refer to domain/codomain and so only make sense for the second approach. **Reflexivity** on the other hand is in this latter category, *for exactly the reason you observe*. It doesn't make sense to say that a given set of ordered pairs is or is not a reflexive relation.

(This is similar to the situation regarding *functions*, where we have a choice of whether or not to include an explicit codomain. Some properties of functions, such as **surjectivity**, only make sense if we include this extra information.)

---

If we need to keep things straight, we can introduce distinguishing terminology (although this is enough of a non-issue that I don't think there's a standard here). For instance:

- A *bare binary relation* is just a set of ordered pairs.
- A *detailed binary relation* is triple $(A,B,R)$ where $R\subseteq A\times B$.

Then the point is this:

> It makes sense to ask whether a detailed binary relation is reflexive, but it does not make sense to ask whether a bare binary relation is reflexive.